# How to replace non string values with Nan in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Tried to do this with pandas.Series.apply function but it consider to be slow on big amount of data. Is there any quicker way to replace values?

Here is what I've tried, but it's slow on big Series (with million items for example)

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 'str1', 'str2', 3])
s.apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else np.nan)
```

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
```

If need also integers add [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

EDIT: You can use `isinstance` with `map`, and also [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
#test 600k
N = 100000
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 'str1', 'str2', 3] * N)


In [152]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else np.nan)
196 ms ± 2.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [153]: %timeit s.map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
174 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [154]: %timeit s.where(s.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))
168 ms ± 3.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [155]: %timeit s.where(pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').isna())
366 ms ± 3.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, if string then dont change value:)